# salesforce.com matrix reports - more than 2 columns on row headings

Tags: report, salesforce

I need to create a donor summary report that provides total donations by donor by year.

I need to provide

```
name address email yr1total yr2total etc...
```

It looks like salesforce only allows two columns in row headings and two columns in column headings. Is there a way to work around this

Or, is there a way to use the tabular report to do the same?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If donations is a single field on the donor's record, it seems like what you're looking to do is attempt to display two columns for the same data within a report.  The best way to do this (well, outside of creating a master-detail relationship with a new custom object named "Donations") would to have formula fields for each of the donation years, and calculate the donation sums in each of them.  That is, as long as you have a way of calculating the year of the donation.

I believe to get the best answer, more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This will work if your donation is a separate object that's linked to Account (I've used Tasks & Events linked to Accounts in my example).

[image: Sample activities matrix report]

1. Create a report in "Matrix format".
2. Drop Account Name on the left pane, Donation's Date on the columns.
3. Columns will default to days. Click the dropdown in the place where I have "Created Date" and select summarizing by year (of course fine-tune to whatever you need).
4. Check date ranges / filter criteria etc obviously if you don't see all data.
5. Click Show -> Hide details.
6. Drop your "Donation Amount" or similar field into place where "Record Count" is displayed. Use "Sum".
7. Optionally deselect Show -> Record Count.

Now you're mentioning that there are only 2 columns so you probably already tried this. Well, common trick is to cheat by using a formula field that would hold your data (separated by comma maybe?). Tabular report would require you to create some helper fields (1 per year) on Account and do some kind of rollup summaries, messy.

If it's for a dashboard you could play with summary report (it can have more groups than 2) and pick chart type table on the dashboard...